# jsPDF output file is empty

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am trying to output a DIV as a PDF File.

I used the basic description from [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) on GitHub

I must have missed something because the file that is downloaded does not appear to have any visible data.  I'm Using OSX Mavericks with Google Chrome, similar result with Safari.  The file is 3kb larger

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="ResultsReport">
     <h3>Hello, this is a H3 tag : testing V2 of btnPDF</h3>

    <p>a pararaph</p>
</div>

<button id="btnPDF" onclick="btnPDF(code);">Generate PDF</button>

<script>
  var code = "UNIQ_ALL";

    function btnPDF(code) {

        var doc = new jsPDF()
        var repPDF = document.getElementById('ResultsReport').innerHTML;
        alert("REP=" + repPDF);
        doc.text(repPDF);
        //doc.text("<h4>This is just a test</h4>");
        doc.save(code + '.pdf');  
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that jspdf library but this works fine:

```js
var code = "UNIQ_ALL";

 function btnPDF(code) {

     var doc = new jsPDF()
     var repPDF = document.getElementById('ResultsReport').innerText;
     doc.text(repPDF, 10, 10); // <-- add 10, 10
     doc.save(code + '.pdf');
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="ResultsReport">
    <h3>Hello, this is a H3 tag : testing V2 of btnPDF</h3>

    <p>a pararaph</p>
  </div>

  <button id="btnPDF" onclick="btnPDF(code);">Generate PDF</button>
</body>

</html>
```

I also changed the `innerHTML` property to `innerText` to extract text instead of HTML.

**Edit**:

Using an older version of jsPDF (1.0.272) you can try the method `fromHTML`. I think is an early stage renderer, so with fancy HTML wouldn't work probably, but for simple stuff should be fine.

html2canvas is not necessary with `fromHTML` but for `addHTML` I think it is.

```js
var code = "UNIQ_ALL";

function btnPDF(code) {

  var doc = new jsPDF();
  doc.fromHTML($("#ResultsReport")[0], 10, 10);
  doc.save(code + '.pdf');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

<div id="ResultsReport">
  <h3>Hello, this is a H3 tag : testing V2 of btnPDF</h3>
  <p>a <b>bold</b> pararaph</p>
</div>

<button id="btnPDF" onclick="btnPDF(code);">Generate PDF</button>
```

Comment: Thanks - yes I have now got data in my PDF file, but I was hoping to retain the HTML, because I want the formatting.

Comment: @mcl To me looks that the formatting is still there, you can still use `innerHTML` and it works but it will write also the tags and I don't think you want that.

Comment: Beaten by the dreaded <CR>, before fully explaining.  Even with innerHTML it is being printed as though it has `<pre>` tags around it.  I was hoping it would retain the CSS styling, like it does when I `window.print` a DIV.  Maybe missed some basic logic

Comment: @mcl To do that you need something like html2pdf, there is a deprecated method on jspdf because they switched to html rasterization: http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/global.html#addHTML

Comment: @marcus Many thanks for the heads up.  I have looked at your link, but my knowledge of JS and Plugins is beyond my skills level.  If it is not a simple example, then I am lost.  I am trying to help a charity, with getting reports from a database and they want PDF output, but they are not confident of using the PDF option in the print dialogue. Hence my attempt to do it for them.

Comment: @mcl I've updated the answer. For simple HTML code you can use an older version of jsPDF, for more complex HTML I don't know and html2canvas would probably be necessary.